# Delete millions of rows using SQLalchemy on MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, mariadb

We have a huge base (~1 To) with billions of rows particularly in one table.
Recently we had to delete 10 of millions of rows in one deletion and we had trouble to do it. When these kinds of deletion are in progress lot of memory is used by the query which could lead to crashes, there could be lock issue also. This kind of deletions will happen more and more.

As of today we delete rows using this code:

```
delete_query = myDB.__table__.delete().where(myDB.foreign_id.in_(foreign_ids_to_delete))
dbsession.execute(delete_query)
```

there is a `commit()` after that.

I thought about adding a limit to delete by batch, but it seems that's it's not handle by SQLAlchemy. Perhaps I could do it in the python side: get all the ids to delete using a select and delete them by batch of 10000 for example. That could lead to performance issues and memory issue on the python side.

Could the `synchronize_session` be one of the reason why the memory is so high?

Comment: If `foreign_ids_to_delete` is a *large* list, then producing the statement object alone will use considerable amounts of memory, not to mention compiling the statement tree to the SQL string. Try using the most recent (stable) version of SQLAlchemy and an [expanding `bindparam()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam.params.expanding) in `in_()`. On the other hand if you are reading the IDs from the DB, why make the round trip to Python at all? `Synchronize_session` is not involved in any way in the code presented here.

Comment: `foreign_ids_to_delete` is not large, probably it the 100 values maximum. The round trip in python would be to loop on IDs in batch to do the deletion and limit the amount of memory used.

Comment: It is not entirely clear if the list of IDs is coming from the DB itself, or from an external source. If they come from the DB, you could loop in the DB as well in batches. By memory used do you refer to the DB server's memory, or the application server's memory?

Comment: The list of ids come from the DB but after several steps in the app. Having all in the DB seems unlikely (multiple condition than depends on parameters). It's not really clear if it comes from sqlalchemy (backend) or from the BDD (on the same server). But it increases a lot during the deletion of the 10s millions rows.

Comment: Techniques for big deletes:  mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB Connector/Python supports native bulk delete operations (which was introduced in MariaDB 10.2) using the binary protocol and `executemany()` method.

Since MariaDB dialect is not included in SQLAlchemy yet (there is an open pull request) you could delete it with a simple python script (table demo contains the records which should be deleted, table delete_keys the id's which should be deleted.

```
import mariadb

conn= mariadb.connect(database="testp")
conn.autocommit= False

cursor=conn.cursor()

# read ids which needs to be deleted
cursor.execute("select id from delete_keys")
ids=cursor.fetchall()
print("Deleting %s rows" % cursor.rowcount)

cursor.executemany("DELETE FROM demo WHERE id=?", ids)
conn.commit()
print("%s rows deleted" % cursor.rowcount)
```

Deleting 20k rows takes about half a second (database server running on the same machine):

```
$ time python3.8 delkeys.py
Deleting 20000 rows
20000 rows deleted

real    0m0,535s
user    0m0,134s
sys     0m0,024s
```